# PIVOT not producing data on a single row

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I am trying to write  PIVOT to generate a row of data that originally sits as multiple rows in the DB. The DB data looks like this (appended)

```
txtSchoolID txtSubjectArchivedName  intSubjectID    intGradeID  intGradeTransposeValue
95406288448    History                  7             634           2
95406288448    History                  7             635           2
95406288448    History                  7             636           2
95406288448    History                  7             637           2
95406288448    History                  7             638           2
95406288448    History                  7             639           2
95406288448    History                  7             640           2
95406288448    History                  7             641           2
95406288448    History                  7             642           2
95406288448    History                  7             643           2
```

What I want to get to is 1 row for each subject and SchoolID with the grades listed as columns.

I have written the following pivot:

```
SELECT        intSubjectID, txtSchoolID, [636] AS Effort, [637] AS Focus, [638] AS Participation, [639] AS Groupwork, [640] AS Rigour, [641] AS Curiosity, [642] AS Initiative,
                [643] AS SelfOrganisation, [644] as Perserverance               
FROM         (SELECT txtSchoolID, intReportTypeID, txtSubjectArchivedName, intSubjectID, intReportProgress, txtTitle, txtForename, txtPreName, txtMiddleNames, 
                txtSurname, txtGender, txtForm, intNCYear, txtSubmitByTitle, txtSubmitByPreName, txtSubmitByFirstname, txtSubmitByMiddleNames, 
                txtSubmitBySurname, txtCurrentSubjectName, txtCurrentSubjectReportName, intReportCycleID, txtReportCycleName, intReportCycleType, 
                intPreviousReportCycle, txtReportCycleShortName, intReportCycleTerm, intReportCycleAcademicYear, dtReportCycleStartDate, 
                dtReportCycleFinishDate, dtReportCyclePrintDate, txtReportTermName, dtReportTermStartDate, dtReportTermFinishDate,  
                intGradeID, txtGradingName, txtGradingOptions, txtShortGradingName, txtGrade, intGradeTransposeValue FROM VwReportsManagementAcademicReports) p
PIVOT
(MAX        (intGradeTransposeValue)
FOR intGradeID IN ([636], [637], [638], [639], [640], [641], [642], [643], [644] )
) AS pvt
WHERE        (intReportCycleID = 142) AND (intReportProgress = 1)
```

However, this is producing this

```
intSubjectID    txtSchoolID Effort  Focus   Participation   Groupwork   Rigour  Curiosity   Initiative  SelfOrganisation    Perserverance
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   74001484142 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL
```

What I want is

```
intSubjectID    txtSchoolID Effort  Focus   Participation   Groupwork   Rigour  Curiosity   Initiative  SelfOrganisation    Perserverance
8               74001484142  3       2            2           2            2        2       2              2                          2
```

Is there a way to get it like this.

I have never tried a PIVOT before, this is my first time, so all help welcome.

Comment: try stripping the inner select down to only the columns that will be used in the pivot and are expected in the output. intSubjectID, txtSchoolID, intGradeTransposeValue, and intGradeID. all other columns will act as a grouping column in the output and can cause this type of non grouped output... not knowing the data i cant say for sure but might be a good place to start

Comment: @SFrejofsky You are amazing. Thank you! I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you got the unexpected result is you have so many unwanted columns in the `Select` in the sub-query and the `pivot` will group them, too.

Your query might be very close to your ideal result: try:

```
SELECT        intSubjectID, txtSchoolID, [636] AS Effort, [637] AS Focus, [638] AS Participation, [639] AS Groupwork, [640] AS Rigour, [641] AS Curiosity, [642] AS Initiative,
                    [643] AS SelfOrganisation, [644] as Perserverance               
    FROM         (SELECT txtSchoolID, intReportTypeID FROM VwReportsManagementAcademicReports) p  --just these two
    PIVOT
    (MAX        (intGradeTransposeValue)
    FOR intGradeID IN ([636], [637], [638], [639], [640], [641], [642], [643], [644] )
    ) AS pvt
    WHERE        (intReportCycleID = 142) AND (intReportProgress = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above - the solution was:

try stripping the inner select down to only the columns that will be used in the pivot and are expected in the output. intSubjectID, txtSchoolID, intGradeTransposeValue, and intGradeID. all other columns will act as a grouping column in the output and can cause this type of non grouped output.

Answer (score 0):

pivot can't return such what you asking for, but you can use another approach:

```
--test dataset
declare @test as table
( txtSchoolID bigint,
  txtSubjectArchivedName varchar(10),
  intSubjectID int,
  intGradeID int,
  intGradeTransposeValue int)
insert into @test 
Values 
(95406288448,'History',7,634,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,635,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,636,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,637,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,638,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,639,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,640,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,641,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,642,2),
(95406288448,'History',7,643,2)

--conditional aggregation
select intSubjectID, 
       txtSchoolID, 
       count(case when intGradeID = 636 then 1 end) AS Effort,
       count(case when intGradeID = 637 then 1 end) AS Focus, 
       count(case when intGradeID = 638 then 1 end) AS Participation, 
       count(case when intGradeID = 639 then 1 end) AS Groupwork, 
       count(case when intGradeID = 640 then 1 end) AS Rigour,
       count(case when intGradeID = 641 then 1 end) AS Curiosity,
       count(case when intGradeID = 642 then 1 end) AS Initiative,
       count(case when intGradeID = 643 then 1 end) AS SelfOrganisation, 
       count(case when intGradeID = 644 then 1 end)  as Perserverance 
from @test
group by intSubjectID, txtSchoolID
```

**[test is here](https://rextester.com/YSUU36318)**